# How to remove option element by index with knockout??

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js

How to remove option element by index?? 
I would like to remove Elements by index
Now function removes all selected items that have that name
example:
I have:
-Marco
-Marco
-Luca

if I select the first item, also clears the second because it has the same name as the first.

HTML:

```
<div class='liveexample'> 
        <form data-bind="submit: addItem">
            New item:
            <input data-bind='value: itemToAdd, valueUpdate: "afterkeydown"' />
            <button type="submit" data-bind="enable: itemToAdd().length > 0">Add</button>
            <input data-bind='value: itemSelected' />
            <button data-bind="enable: false">Press space key to remove selected element</button>
            <p>Your items:</p>
            <select multiple="multiple" width="50" data-bind="options: items, click: selOpt, event: { keypress: selRemoveOpt}"> </select>
        </form>
    </div>
```

JS:

```
self.selOpt =  function(data,event){ //select element
                    var x=event.target.value;
                    var index = $(event.target).index();
                    console.log("index"+index);
                    self.indice(index);
                    self.itemSelected(x);
                    /*
                    self.removeItem(x);
                    */
                };

self.selRemoveOpt =  function(data,event){ // remove element select
                    var x=event.target.value;
                    console.log(self.indice);
                    if (event.keyCode === 32) {
                        self.removeItem(x);
                    }
                };
```

Comment: Message: $index is not defined.  Can you write the solution please?

Comment: You can use splice to remove an item by its index. From the knockout docs: "splice() — Removes and returns a given number of elements starting from a given index. For example, myObservableArray.splice(1, 3) removes three elements starting from index position 1 (i.e., the 2nd, 3rd, and 4th elements) and returns them as an array." http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html